# Spring Controller Unit test exception :Caused by: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing

Im getting the following Error on running unit test for Spring controller:
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125) at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108) at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190) at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132)
```

My intention is to write unit test case for imagecontroller. Suggest any other alternative also. The image controller is returning file and rendering it in localhost server:http://localhost:8081/e46713403433b7ceee07bf1d996f86fd.

This is my ImageController class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3001")
public class ImageController {

    @Autowired
    private ImageRepository imageRepository;

    // Return the image from the database using ResponseEntity

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> fromDatabaseAsResEntity(@PathVariable("id") String image_key)
            throws SQLException, IOException {
        Optional<DicomImage> imagePath = imageRepository.findById(image_key);
        ArrayList<DicomImage> parsedPath = new ArrayList<>();
        imagePath.ifPresent(parsedPath::add);
        String stringPath = parsedPath.get(0).getPath();
        String b = stringPath.substring(stringPath.indexOf('/') + 1);
        File dicomImage = new File("/usr/src/app/dicom_images/" + stringPath);
        InputStreamResource returnImage = null;
        if(dicomImage != null) {
            returnImage = new InputStreamResource(new FileInputStream(dicomImage));

        } else {
            System.out.println("File not found");
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM).body(returnImage);

    }

}
```

This is the ImageControllerTest class

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class ImageControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    
    private ImageRepository imageRepository;
    private ImageController imageController;
    

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnDefaultMessage() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/e46713403433b7ceee07bf1d996f86fd")).andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM));
    }
}
```

Application.properties:

```
# MySQL database connection strings
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://pb_mysql:3306/test
spring.datasource.username=pb
spring.datasource.password=pb@123
# JPA property settings
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
```

Comment: Kindly share the complete stack trace. from the given error looks like there is no communication between your app and database

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
 at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125)
 at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108)
 at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190)
 at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test the behavior of your controller, I would suggest writing an integration test that is annotated with `@WebMvcTest`.
With this annotation, Spring Boot will only configure the components of your web layer. The dependency on the database will be mocked away.

Your test would look something like this:

```
@WebMvcTest({ImageController.class})
public class ImageControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    
    @MockBean
    private ImageRepository imageRepository;
    

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnDefaultMessage() throws Exception {

        String imageKey = "e46713403433b7ceee07bf1d996f86fd";
        Optional<DicomImage> mockedDicomImage = //initialize the mock that will be returned by the repository

        doReturn(mockedDicomImage).when(imageRepository).findById(eq(imageKey));

        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/".concat(imageKey))).andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM));
    }
}
```

For more information on `@WebMvcTest` you can have a look at [this blog post](https://jschmitz.dev/2021/04/14/how_to_test_the_web_layer_of_your_spring_boot_application_with_webmvctest/) of mine.

Comment: Now it throws this error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.startsWith(String)" because "requestUri" is null

Comment: When I remove this.mockmvc line its passing. Full stack trace: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.startsWith(String)" because "requestUri" is null
 at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockHttpServletRequestBuilder.updatePathRequestProperties(MockHttpServletRequestBuilder.java:685)
 at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockHttpServletRequestBuilder.buildRequest(MockHttpServletRequestBuilder.java:607)
 at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:157)
 at org.ge.controller.ImageControllerTest.shouldReturnDefaultMessage